# FlutterNativeSplash.removeAfter(initialisation) renders next screen before initialisation completes

Tags: flutter, async-await, sharedpreferences, splash-screen

I am using flutter_native_splash package and shared_preferneces to store my app data. I have the following code in my main.dart file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'home_management.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.removeAfter(initialization);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

void initialization(BuildContext context) async {
  // Initialise shared preferences
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  // Initialise user location and store it in shared preferences
  Location _location = Location();
  bool? _serviceEnabled;
  PermissionStatus? _permissionGranted;
  LocationData? _locationData;

  _serviceEnabled = await _location.serviceEnabled();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    _serviceEnabled = await _location.requestService();
  }

  _permissionGranted = await _location.hasPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
    _permissionGranted = await _location.requestPermission();
  }

  _locationData = await _location.getLocation();
  sharedPreferences.setDouble('latitude', _locationData.latitude!);
  sharedPreferences.setDouble('longitude', _locationData.longitude!);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      home: const HomeManagement(),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using HomeManagement to manage my Pages with a bottom navigation bar, and the first page to load is RestaurantsMap() which looks as below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class RestaurantsMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const RestaurantsMap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RestaurantsMap> createState() => _RestaurantsMapState();
}

class _RestaurantsMapState extends State<RestaurantsMap> {
  late Future<SharedPreferences> sharedPreferences;

  @override
  void initState() {
    sharedPreferences = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Restaurants Map'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: sharedPreferences,
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              print(snapshot.data!.getDouble('latitude'));

              return const Center(
                child: Text('Start building something awesome! '),
              );
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I am accessing the latitude in RestaurantsMap inside the FutureBuilder, I am getting a null printed by the following line of code:

```
print(snapshot.data!.getDouble('latitude'));
```

Using print statements inside the `initialization()` function after `sharedPreferences.setDouble` returns the data, so the only logical explanation is that I am accessing the `getDouble('latitude')` before it is getting set.
Any observations/solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers, if anyone faces the same issue, just update to the latest version for `flutter_native_splash`. An update has been released that gives more flexibility to make a call to remove the splash screen.

Here is the new readme - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#3-set-up-app-initialization-optional

Comment: Source - https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/287